# React custom editable grid is preserving values from deleted rows

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fluentui-react, detailslist

I am using fluent-ui's `DetailsList` to render a table. I am trying to convert this into a simple editable grid. The 1st column is a readonly string, the 2nd column is an editable `TextField` and the 3rd column is the delete button. I have provided ItemColumn rendering function so that each column can be rendered as desired. See the following demo:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/detailslist-delete-broken-gfnrgn?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.tsx%3A74%2C43

I have provided 2 rows, with the first row having the default value in the textfield of "Blue", and the second row having blank.

**The problem:** when I click on the delete button in the first row, the color is preserved at that index. So now it looks like Beagal's favorite color is "Blue", when it was in fact John's. This only seems to be a problem with Input columns, and not readonly columns like "Name" in this example, which is why "Beagal" correctly shifts up upon delete of the row above it. This is extra confusing because when I log the `listItems` state variable, it looks correct, so it's like the grid isn't properly re-rendering the `TextField` or something.

How to I ensure that when I delete a row, the `TextField` doesn't show the data from the row below it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<TextField>` is using a `defaultValue`. This means the component is "uncontrolled" in the sense it manages its state internally. Seemingly because of a slightly unexpected quirk of Fluent's behaviour, when the `defaultValue` changes it is ignored and it retains the internal copy it already has.

You can demonstrate this by setting a [`key`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#resetting-state-with-a-key) that forces the text field to remount completely when the row deletion causes that item to be in a new position:

```
<TextField key={item.name + index} defaultValue={item.favColor}></TextField>
```

This causes all the `TextField`s to essentially be removed and readded -- circumventing the problem since the `TextField` will be forced to grab the new initial value.

But I suspect you actually wanted to be editing the dataset itself with the new value. I.e. using `TextField` as a *controlled* component via the `value` prop. The `onChange` prop here then actually updates the `favColor` field for the data for the row in question (with the new value, each time a keystroke happens) by deep updating `listItems`.

```
        case "favColorColumn": {
          return (
            <TextField
              onChange={(e, newVal) => {
                setListItems((prevListItems) =>
                  Object.assign([], prevListItems, {
                    [index]: { ...prevListItems[index], favColor: newVal },
                  })
                );
              }}
              value={item.favColor}
            ></TextField>
          );
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to set the key on the `DetailsList` and didn't realize I had to set it on the `TextField` itself. That being said, the "controlled" version is what I was actually looking for. I created an updated link where I implemented that: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fixed-detailslist-r7g59v?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.tsx%3A56%2C6

Comment: Do you know why when I change the type to "Number" it stops working? E.g. "Fav color" becomes "fav number". If I type in "123" into the first row and delete it, I'm left with single character "1". Curiously, if I type in just a single character "1", I have to backspace twice to delete it. See: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/detailslist-delete-number-qwd6sk?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.tsx

Comment: Its because of needing to detect more precisely what a falsey value is. You should use `value={item.favNumber === undefined ? "" : String(item.favNumber)}` and inside the object assign `favNumber: newVal !== "" ? Number(newVal) : undefined,`

Comment: Thought process. `item.favNumber?.toString()` would return `undefined` when `item.favNumber` is `undefined`. You want `value` to _always_ be a string. So we detect this scenario and set empty string. For the setting part, you should detect `newVal` is literally an empty string to avoid any weird equivalence vs equality stuff in js.